# Why did I get reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

When I get more reputation, I get a green +5 or +2 (for example) in the top menu. Clicking on it, I can see which question generated that reputation. However, that's all I get to know. How can I know exactly why I got that reputation?

This is not a duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) because I want a page or some automatic message from Stack Exchange telling me explicitly why I got the reputation I actually got, not a general description on how reputation is given.

Comment: Did you check this [history track](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/357779/barbara?tab=reputation) in your profile already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: @AnthonyPham that question does not tell a user how to find out what the reputation change was for. All it does is give a list of possible reputation changes.

Comment: Agree with @Catija this isn't a dupe. At least not of that question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way (but requires each site to be visited) is to look at your reputation page. Yours on Mathematics is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/391944/barbara?tab=reputation), for example.

As you can see, it tells you what each reputation change is for...

That being said, you can usually tell simply based on knowing what type of post it is...

If you wrote the question, you're probably getting +5... because +5 is the same as an upvote on a question. Or, if you accept an answer on your question, you get +2.

If you wrote an answer, you're probably getting +10... because each upvote on an answer earns you +10.

If you didn't write the post, then you've probably suggested an edit, so you're getting the +2 bonus for having an edit accepted.

So, in the end, you don't really need to go and look at it if you can memorize what the point values do.

Odd numbers like  +8 or +3 are generally due to a mixture of up and down votes.

Comment: Odd numbers can happen due to rep caps or the new Documentation Beta (at Stack Overflow) point system (i.e an upvote on a topic is +1 rep)

Comment: This user has never rep capped and is not a member of SO. This isn't intended to be exhaustive, regardless... the main point is pointing out the link on the user's profile.

Comment: @Catija. Thanks. The Reputation page on my profile is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Its worth remembering that reputation that's 'returned' or 'taken away' due to specific events like users or questions being deleted might not be itemised in your reputation page.

Answer (score 5):

You get these rep changes:

- +15 for getting your answer accepted
- +10 for an upvote on your answer
- +5 for an upvote on your question
- +2 for an accepted edit
- +2 for accepting an answer (thanks @catija)
- -1 for downvoting an answer
- -2 for being downvoted

There are also [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) which can give you anything from 50 to 500 rep increasing in steps of 50.

A full list can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

I think that's all but you can also get combinations e.g. +1 could be one question upvote and 2 downvotes.

Comment: You forgot accepting an answer +2.

Comment: Bounties as well (50 to 500 at intervals of 50)